# Should my photo based app store two different-sized versions of uploaded images?

Tags: image, firebase-realtime-database, storage, firebase-storage, android-glide

My app is a photo sharing app that behaves similarly to Instagram.
I am wondering what is the right approach when it comes to file storage and image sizes.

Specifically the two questions on my mind are:

1. Should I keep two versions of each photo, one big for the full size view and one small for faster loading thumbnails? Or should one full size one would be enough and the loading time would be redundant to the user?
2. To what size should I resize the uploaded photos (the full size ones)? What would be a good balance of quality and size?
3. List item

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Should I keep two versions of each photo, one big for the full size view and one small for faster loading thumbnails?

In general be very cognizant of the resources that you use on the user's device. If you're showing a list of thumbnails to the user, and they have to click on a thumbnail to see the full size photo, then: think about on how many thumbnails the user will click. Or even better: measure it. Most likely that will be a fairly low fraction, in which case you can save your users a significant amount of bandwidth by only sending thumbnails.

> To what size should I resize the uploaded photos (the full size ones)?

There is no single size that works for every user and device, so I'd recommend resizing the image to multiple formats, and then selecting the best fit for each user based on their device.

The thing to keep in mind is that any bandwidth that you use is a hurdle to adoption, always because it take time to load things (don't overestimate the average bandwidth of your users), but also because many users pay by the amount of data they load. Any hurdle you put up, will lower adoption. The more hurdles you can remove, the more likely users are to start/keep using your app.